# SQL CASE and ELSE

Tags: case

Hello I am considering the following:

```
CASE 
   WHEN xyz.something = 1 THEN 'SOMETEXT'
   WHEN xyz.somethingelse = 1 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXT'
   WHEN xyz.somethingelseagain = 2 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE'
   ELSE 'SOMETHING UNKNOWN'
```

Is this effectively doing a `ELSE` in between two `WHEN`, ie `xyz.something = 1` has priority over `xyz.somethingelse = 1` ?

If not, is this the right approach?

```
CASE WHEN xyz.something = 1 THEN 'SOMETEXT' ELSE 
CASE WHEN xyz.somethingelse = 1 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXT' ELSE 
CASE WHEN xyz.somethingelseagain = 2 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE'
       ELSE 'SOMETHING UNKNOWN'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CASE` expression is evaluated from top to bottom, if no WHEN is matched ELSE is used. You need an END for each CASE. Your first expression:

```
CASE WHEN xyz.something = 1 THEN 'SOMETEXT'
     WHEN xyz.somethingelse = 1 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXT'
     WHEN xyz.somethingelseagain = 2 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE'
     ELSE 'SOMETHING UNKNOWN'
END
```

is similar to:

```
if xyz.something == 1:
    return 'SOMETEXT'
else if xyz.somethingelse = 1:
    return 'SOMEOTHERTEXT'
...
else:
    return 'SOMETHING UNKNOWN'
```

Your second expression:

```
CASE WHEN xyz.something = 1 THEN 'SOMETEXT' 
     ELSE CASE WHEN xyz.somethingelse = 1 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXT' 
               ELSE CASE WHEN xyz.somethingelseagain = 2 THEN 'SOMEOTHERTEXTGOESHERE'
                         ELSE 'SOMETHING UNKNOWN'
                    END
          END
END
```

is similar to:

```
if xyz.something == 1:
    return 'SOMETEXT'
else:
    if xyz.somethingelse = 1:
        return 'SOMEOTHERTEXT'
    else:
        if ...

        else:
            return 'SOMETHING UNKNOWN'
```

Both expressions evaluate to one string.

Not sure if this answers your question, can you elaborate on what you are trying to express?

Comment: thank you for answer. So if `the CASE expression is evaluated from top to bottom`, it seems to me that both expressions are resulting in the same logical output. I want to use the simplest (and fastest) code, which might the expression 1?

Comment: I would not expect much performance gain, but I would prefer the first one.

Comment: The point of a CASE really is that it is much simpler to read than a series of if/else if/else statements.  Logically they are the same but internally they will get translated to much the same.

Comment: The pseudo code was just to demonstrate semantics for the OP, there are no IF THEN ELSE construct in SQL (unless procedural parts of the language are included).